# Convert type double to number field _id mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to convert double type to number type of  field _id in console mongodb.
I have tried many ways but not working.

I tried:

```
db.videos.find({_id : {$exists : true}})
         .forEach( function(obj)
                   { obj._id = new NumberInt(obj._id ); db.videos.save(obj); }
                 )
```

Comment: Try to specify what you already did for this.

Comment: I have try 

db.videos.find({_id : {$exists : true}}).forEach( function(obj) { obj._id = new NumberInt(obj._id ); db.videos.save(obj); } );

Comment: Why do you want to convert your `_id` doubles to ints? Different numeric representations (double, int, long) are intentionally equivalent for comparison in queries (although you can add `$type` criteria for a find). Inserting a new document with an `_id` that's the integer equivalent of an existing document's `_id` will result in a duplicate key exception (try your shell query with one document rather than a forEach loop). If you really need to do this, you'll need to delete the existing documents and reinsert with the preferred `_id`.

Comment: Is this an instance of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/229922) ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I want to backup and restore but I have been done and datatype is int, not auto change to double

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/) in your code. Possible that it gets you more information

Comment: How does your solution look?

Comment: I used MEANJS create model schema in server side. 
1. I use $http get database from store.
2. I use $http post to controller in server...This controller call function insert to database. this is my way to convert